# while adding image to database in django 3.1 showing this error

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add images to database it shows this error message.

```
STATIC_ROOT = posixpath.join(*(BASE_DIR.split(os.path.sep)+['static']))
AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = posixpath.join(*(BASE_DIR.split(os.path.sep)+['static']))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'images')
MEDIA_URL = '/images'
```

Comment: What is `BASE_DIR`?

Comment: The error message is pretty straight forward. What part are you not understanding?

Comment: BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error you are getting `BASE_DIR` looks like it is `pathlib.WindowsPath` ([docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)).

You should consider manipulating your path using the methods exposed by that library but if you really want to cast it as a string, just do this:

```py
str(BASE_DIR)
```

If you want its absolute representation, do this:

```py
str(BASE_DIR.resolve())
```